# Can't connect to external Oracle database from Glassfish pool, but I can from DBeaver

Tags: oracle, jdbc, glassfish, dbeaver

First, I'm sorry if I say something wrong, English isn't my first language. Also, I'm changing the real names for security (and NDA) reasons

Whenever I try to connect from my Java project with Glassfish to the external database with the URL "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//HOST:1521/SID", DBUSER=auser, DBPASSWORD=apass123, it throws

```
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

Here's how I configured the Glassfish pool:

[DataSource and Driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bReVL.png)

[URL, DBUSER and DBPASSWORD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv0vQ.png)

Glassfish's domain.xml

```
<jdbc-connection-pool datasource-classname="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" name="NamePool" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource">
      <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//HOST:1521/SID"></property>
      <property name="DBPASSWORD" value="apass123"></property>
      <property name="DBUSER" value="auser"></property>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
<jdbc-resource pool-name="NamePool" jndi-name="jdbc/jndiORA"></jdbc-resource>
```

My project's connect.java, throws error at `dataSource.getConnection()`

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public static void Connect(String query) throws NamingException {
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/jndiORA");
        try (Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection()) {
            try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            }
        }
}
```

But when I try to connect with DBeaver using the same credentials, it DOES work!

[DBeaver Oracle Connection Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyhWD.png)

[DBeaver connection, shows the schemas and can do queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AerSj.png)

Tried some of the answers provided in similar threads, with no positive results

- Using "auser" and "apass123" instead of auser and apass123
- Escaping first character with \ (\auser and \apass)
- Downloaded last version of ojdbc6.jar

I'm not the admin of the external database, so couldn't try the "alter system set sec_case_sensitive_logon" solution

Thank you very much for everything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties should be `user` and `password`, not `dbuser` and `dbpassword`

```
<jdbc-connection-pool datasource-classname="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" name="NamePool" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource">
      <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//HOST:1521/SID"></property>
      <property name="USER" value="auser"></property>
      <property name="PASSWORD" value="apass123"></property>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
```

Also `/SID` is actually `/service-name`, so check that's correct, and that you're attempting to the right CDB/PDB - though from DBeaver screenshots are a bit confusing, as that seems to be specifying a SID in the connection panel but showing a service-name URL in the second image.

Comment: Tried to change the names with `USER` and `PASSWORD`, but now I got an IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection. I previously had this error, but once I got the URL right, just appeared the logon error.

Answer (score 0):

check your connection URL (Example: jdbc:oracle:thin:@myhost:1521/myorcldbservicename). Always use servicename instead of SID. Also, verify if your connection is working by using a plain Java program [DataSourceSample.java](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/blob/master/java/jdbc/ConnectionSamples/DataSourceSample.java). This will eliminate any database related issues.